# SQLite column can't be updated to any value but zero (real type)

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

Hi I'm trying to create a three fields table (date,text,real),
I can insert and update the first two fields but can't set or update the last one.

```
createSQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ACTIVITIES (MYDATE DATETIME PRIMARY KEY, ACTIVITY TEXT , LENGTH REAL);";
```

try to insert

```
char *update = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ACTIVITIES (MYDATE, ACTIVITY , LENGTH) VALUES (?, ? ,?);";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update , -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 1, valueToWrite);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [task UTF8String], -1, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, 1.5);
}
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg);
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

The first two values are updated but the last one remains 0 even if I'm writing a value like 1.5 or put a double variable with a different value.

Comment: You should also add the code you're using to read the data back from sqlite.  It's possible the rows are updated correctly in the database but there's a mistake or data conversion when you pull it out of the database.